# Collapse RadFileExplorer using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, telerik, rad-controls

I have a RadFileExplorer, my problem is I can't find a way to collapse the node after close of a pop-up page in javascript. My code doesn't work.

```
function collapseNodes() {
        $find("<%= RadAjaxPanel1.ClientID%>").ajaxRequestWithTarget("<%= RadAjaxPanel1.UniqueID %>", "Refresh");
        var explorer = $find("<%=RadFileExplorer1.ClientID%>"); 
        var tree = explorer.get_tree();
        var nodes = tree.get_allNodes(); --> this part is not working
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {   --> this part is not working
            if (node.get_expanded())     --> this part is not working
                node.set_expanded(false);--> this part is not working
        });
    }
```

---

```
<telerik:RadFileExplorer runat="server" ID="RadFileExplorer1" Width="100%" EnableOpenFile="false" 
    EnableCreateNewFolder="true" OnItemCommand="RadFileExplorer1_ItemCommand" OnExplorerPopulated="RadFileExplorer1_ExplorerPopulated"  

    DisplayUpFolderItem="false" >
    <keyboardshortcuts delete="delete" uploadfile="Ctrl+u" newfolder="Ctrl+n" />
</telerik:RadFileExplorer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **get_nodes()** first from the treeview object: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreeview.html.

Then, **get_count()** will return the count so you can make a for loop, there is no forEach method in the nodes collection: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreenodecollection.html.

Only then can you use the given node's client-side API for the get_expanded() and set_expanded(): http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreenode.html. Take a look at the example below the get_nodes() method from the first article.